# Shape Key Driver not working

Tags: armature, drivers, shape-keys

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my driver, it's not doing anything at all.  Here's the setup for my driver:

[image]

[image]

When I rotate the arm nothing happens!

[image]

[image]

As you can see the value for the shape key didn't change at all.  What am I doing wrong?  Please help me fix this, thanks!

Comment: Your driver is displaying an error of some sort. That is going to be the most likely cause. Try clicking the 'Update Dependencies' button and see if that helps. Otherwise it may have something to do with an incorrect axis being used. At the bottom of the 3d view change from Global to Local, then select your upper arm bone and check the axis. My guess is it won't be the Y axis. Also, does the shape key value change if you rotate the arm the other way?

Comment: Ahh, you're right, the shape key is applied when I rotate it on the X axis instead of the Y!  And when I changed the type of rotation to the X axis the shape key is applied when I rotate the arm on the Y axis.  So everything's backwards, the Y is X and X is Y.  How do I fix the bone to be on the correct axis?

Comment: It's not that the axes are necessarily wrong, it's just that they are not lined up with the global axes, which is also not an issue. There is also an option in the display panel of the armature tab of the properties panel where you can display the axes for all of the bones if that helps.